# Searching through a list for specific text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble limiting a list to only add unique items this is what I have so far

```
function addTab(tabName)
{
    var tabList=$("#pageContent ul").find("li").text();
    if($("#pageContent ul li:contains('"+tabList+"')").length<1)
    {
        $("#pageContent ul").append("<li>"+tabName+"</li>");
    }
    else
    {   

    }
}
```

but it doesn't work I'm not sure what's wrong and from what I can tell this should be the best way to do it.

I was going to use jQuery UI tabs but my layout uses floats and messes with the tabs widget

Comment: The selector in `tabList` and in the conditional right after it are practically identical.  Do you want to check if a different `ul` contains?

Comment: Can you provide enough HTML for someone to be able to reproduce this please

Comment: You never need `.length<1` `length` returns 0 or a positive integer which when compared as a boolean is respectively false or true. `if (someobject.length)` is enough

Answer (score 0):

You are getting text content of all li elements and then try to select li elements that contain that specific text, this doesn't make sense, you don't even use `tabName` in your filtering logic, try the following using `filter` method.

```
function addTab(tabName) {
    var $e = $("#pageContent ul");
    var n = $e.find("li").filter(function(){
        var t = this.textContent || this.innerText;
        return t === tabName
    }).length;

    if (n === 0) {
        $e.append("<li>"+tabName+"</li>");
    } else {  
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that works great, thank you. I did accidently leave the tablist part in there but I wasn't using it. I tried .find before but it wasn't working but the implementaion in the answer was perferct